# List all files to be compiled by Gradle

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm looking for option to list all files to be compiled by Gradle. Something like `gradle dependencies` but for packages/files. I'm trying to setup mixed java/scala, robolectric + junit/scalatest env for Android development and need such functionality for debug as it looks like my `src/androidTest/scala/*` files are not included in `test` task.

Answer (score 1):

I'd run the build with `--info` or `--debug` first. If that doesn't help you can start looking for more verbose logging.